# Help me understand Vector Spaces (proving linear spaces)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Please help me understand each part clearly. Please don't give general answers, it's easier for me to  understand concepts by doing specific questions and learning about them.

[image]

---

**(i)** The reason is its not closed under addition.

I know this because I have watched Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra vedios. But he explains in a graphical method that helped me understand why it's true, since spaces are planes, if you take the union, you take all points on the two planes, so if you add points that aren't in common, you end up outside the space.

But can someone please show me an example, with real values how the addition doesn't work out? A vector that can't be formed using the additon in $V_1UV_2$.

I know it only from a graphical point of view, Please use my question above, to answer.

I tried my best to find a vector that I can't get using this question , I couldn't.

---

**(ii)** This part I totally understand that the basis is $b_1 , b_2$ And the dimensions is pretty straightforward looking at the two vectors, it's 2.

---

**(iii)**

For the third part I prove the following three :

1. Contains zero vector- let $q=0 , r=0, s=0$.  Then you get zero vector.
2. Closed under addition - I don't quite know the perfect (I don't know) proof for this, Please help.
3. Closed under multiplication- This either , I don't know.

> My book says it's enough to show that its closed under addition (I don't know why this is enough in this case).

For the dimensions, do I take the column space and  do reduced row echelons form and find the rank and then dimension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas.
**For the first:**
To show that this is not a linear subspace, consider $b_4-b_3$. Is it contained in $V_1 \cup V_2$? Remember that $V_1$ consists of all linear combinations of certain vectors and the same with $V_2$. This should help you with this question.
**For the third:**
Closed under addition is immediate, since if you have two vector of the form $q_1b_2+r_1b_3+s_1b_4$ and $q_2b_2+r_2b_3+s_2b_4$ for $q_i,r_i,s_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $i=1,2$, then the sum is just $(q_1+q_2)b_2+(r_1+r_2)b_3+(s_1+s_2)b_4$ which is clearly in the subspace.
Note also that the zero vector is contained in this subset and so are all scalar multiples of a vector in this subset. Thus, this is a subspace.

Comment: Fore the first part $b_4-b_3$ is $0b_1 +0b_2-1b_3+b_4$ , so how is this not there in $V_1 U V_2$ ?

Comment: (+1) Also , for the third part :) Thanks a lot, and how do I show that the dimension is 3? How do I prove scalar multiple ???

Comment: $V_1 \cup V_2$ is not the subspace generated by $b_1,b_2,b_3$ and $b_1,b_2,b_4$, rather it is the union of the subspace generated by $b_1,b_2,b_3$ and $b_1,b_2,b_4$. So while you are correct that $b_4-b_3$ is in the subspace generated by $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$, it is **not** in $V_1 \cup V_2$.

Comment: For showing that the dimension is three, show linear independence of $b_2$ ,$b_3$ and $b_4$.

Comment: Oh thank you very much, I didn't know this :) So what is the Union generated from? What are the vectors that generates V1 U V2 ? :)

Comment: Thank you very much :D I owe you big time. The most important question : what is the  vectors that generate the union ?

Comment: The union is not a subspace. However, $V_1 \cup V_2$ consists of vectors that can be written **either** as $q_1b_1+r_1b_2+s_1b_3$ or $q_2b_1+q_2b_2+s_2b_4$ for $q_i,r_i,s_i \in \mathbb{R}$. So, you can see that $b_4-b_3$ (or if you wish, $b_3+b_4$ ) is not in the subspace, simply owing to the fact that you can't write $b_3+b_4$ as $q_1b_1+r_1b_2+s_1b_3$ or $q_2b_1+r_2b_2+s_2b_4$.

Comment: Thank you very very much :) I really appreciate it :)